# Angular JIT & AOT in memory factory classes - are they actually generated or just in-memory?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Using the Angular CLI, with the default `ng new` app, I created a **JIT** and an **AOT** project to compare file sizes, bundling, inspect in Chrome DevTools etc.

I then served both of these, and inspected the files in Chrome DevTools
 - JIT: ng serve
 - AOT: ng serve --aot

For the JIT version, the ngFactory files have all be compiled by the JIT compiler (for AOT, these exact functions are in the pre-compiled main bundle).

The [documentation says](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/aot-compiler.html#!#compile) that the ng class factories are created **in memory** in the JIT version of the app

> JIT compilation generates these same NgFactories in memory where they
>   are largely invisible.

When I veiw the JIT app in DevTools, (see screenshot) I can see the JIT compiled factory files under **no domain**. Are these actually in-memory, or does the compiler generate temporary files, or what??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are in browser memory when you're running JIT compilation.

Angular generates them through `new Function()`

For example:

```
var expression = `
    function Yurzui() {
      this.param1 = name;
    }
    Yurzui.prototype.hello = function() {
      return 'Hello ' + this.param1;
    }
    return Yurzui;
    //# sourceURL=/yurzui/say-hello/my.factory.js
`;

var func = new Function('name', expression);

var clazz = func('Some name');
alert((new clazz()).hello());
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/L4IP9eKILDlnr3heyE8Z?p=preview)**

[image]

Comment: Ah, perfect! I've had a look at the compiler in github now that I know what to look for, and see the use of 'new Function()' there. ...packages/compiler/src/output/output_jit.ts    Thanks a lot.